# Magento2: Salable quanttity

Tags: magento2

I use script for update product qty.

Example:
product one have

- quantity: 0 pcs
- salable quantity: 0 pcs

Now I update product and is available total 11 quantity. 
https://prnt.sc/rmmeuo

But for Salable quantity still display 0 pcs and product in not available on sale on website. How to solve this issue ans sync  qty ==> salable quantity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a view per website that need to exist. Check if you have the inventory_stock_1 view in your database

If not, this might work:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED VIEW `inventory_stock_1` AS
select
    distinct `legacy_stock_status`.`product_id` AS `product_id`,
    `legacy_stock_status`.`website_id` AS `website_id`,
    `legacy_stock_status`.`stock_id` AS `stock_id`,
    `legacy_stock_status`.`qty` AS `quantity`,
    `legacy_stock_status`.`stock_status` AS `is_salable`,
    `product`.`sku` AS `sku`
from
    (`cataloginventory_stock_status` `legacy_stock_status`
join `catalog_product_entity` `product` on
    ((`legacy_stock_status`.`product_id` = `product`.`entity_id`)))
```

Comment: After run mysql query still no result and display 0 qty

Comment: try to reindex now

Comment: Working correct for all new products. Thank you,